# What Encoding is Used in this PDF Metadata?

Tags: pdf, encoding, metadata

I'm looking at the binary of Adobe's [PDF Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf) document, and I'm wondering encoding is being used in the values of the metadata here:

```
<<
/Producer <30B9883671A1867F59929DEDF9AF32BC0029CF5414D3744A3273BCA8E7319382EA151980>
/Subject <30BE953B76E0A2306F8F8FFBFCA67E9D1D6A8F17418D200C1B6EEE88E726DAC4CE3E2CC1>
/Creator <37A89B34768D93347889CEAFBEF3>
/Title <219EBC7941A5943A6F9E80FAF5EF7E8D1A60881E04A630452968F38B>
/Author <30BE953B76E0A1266E8F8BF4E3E317B71166880A4B9135583865>
/ModDate <35E0C86923F1C36E2FC2DEA0A1F56BEF5F39C25D14D373>
/CreationDate <35E0C86923F1C36E2CCCDFAEA1F36EE128>
>>
```

So far, I can't find anything in the documentation or the ISO standard about this, and this is the only PDF I've seen so far with encoded metadata values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is standard encoding but the text strings have been *encrypted*. See **3.5 Ecryption** in that same reference guide.

When inspecting a PDF, you should always start with reading the *trailer dictionary* (see **3.4.4 File Trailer**). In your document this contains an `/Encrypt` key:

```
<<
   /Size 31667
   /ID [<19574527ECBF00E3EC0373879833EEF6> <24EE9EDB7DE40DB862FDB4C5D3493585>]
   /Info 7 0 R
   /Root 1 0 R
   /Encrypt 31666 0 R
>>
```

which is "required if document is encrypted".